# Can Ubuntu Touch run on a Toshiba Encore Mini WT7-C16 Tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

Will Ubuntu Touch work on this tablet?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The [list of unofficial supported devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) includes two Toshiba devices, none of which are the one you showed.

Here is the [main page for installing Ubuntu on devices](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/), look at the Supported Devices section for more information.